# How to convert elasticquery into kibana URL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

i am using kibana 6 dashboard to show visualization.

i have a elastic query like below and it need to pass in kibana dashbaord URL :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "jt_tax.keyword": "Partner"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "jt_tax.keyword": "IT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to parse the ELASTIC QUERY into  query parameter in Kibana dashboard Url?

Comment: very nice query though

Comment: See this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dashboard-search-parameter-via-url/84385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similiar issues:

Passing the filter as part of the kibana url:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dashboard-search-parameter-via-url/84385

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/passing-parameters-or-filter-in-kibana-url-from-web-app/141568

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/pass-filter-to-dashboard-url-in-markdown-menu/50991